# OMNET++ : Working with VEINS, INET and MIXIM

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet, mixim

I need to implement an adaptive routing protocol using OMNET++

Is the sub module `channel control` still available from the INET framework because I cannot find it. Thus I have installed MIXIM. Can I work with Veins to connect SUMO and OMNET, and INET and MIXIM for the compound modules of vehicles and RSUs?

Thank You

Comment: Using INET for the routing and VEINS for the simulation of 802.11p and the connection to SUMO is most likely sufficient for what you want to do. VEINS is based on MIXIM -- unless you need some specific thing from it, I'd recommend using VEINS as a basis.

Comment: Thank you for your relay. With regard to the `channel control` sub module, is that found in the INET Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What used to be `channelControl` modules in earlier INET versions are called now `radioMedium`, but they have the same task. Coordinate the radio transmissions between the nodes.